# Shift register that can shift few bit positions at once a.k.a per clock cycle

Tags: verilog, multiplication, divider, shift-register

Does anyone of you know if there is such a shift register topology that can fit my requirement as stated in title?

For example,

100101 left shifted 3 bit positions in one clk cycle:

100101 -> 101000

If there is, please kindly tell me the name so that I could do more deep research. And also if possible, the `model/object` name in verilog HDL.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: more specifically, I am doing research on multiplication & division of 32 bits. Thus, shifting is one of the needed way as far as I know.

Comment: What is a 'model/object name in Verilog HDL'?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a **barrel shifter**, and that is the canonical form for a shifter that allows for a variable shift length. The barrel shifter is a combinational logic block, not a method of interconnecting flip-flops, but you can make a barrel shift *register* by adding a register to it.